# Xamarin C# - Set a TextView from a different Layout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, methods, elapsedtime

I have a problem.

This is the simplified code I use:

```
public void LoadOrderPage()
{
    Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager SummaryWalletSwitcher =
          FindViewById<Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager>(Resource.Id.SummaryWalletSwitcher);

    List<View> viewlist = new List<View>();
    viewlist.Add(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AgentSummary, null, false));
    viewlist.Add(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AgentWallet, null, false));
    SummaryWalletAdapter ViewSwitchAdapter = new SummaryWalletAdapter(viewlist);
    SummaryWalletSwitcher.Adapter = ViewSwitchAdapter;

    LoadAgentInfo(null, null);

    Timer AgentInfo_Timer = new Timer();
    AgentInfo_Timer.Interval = 1000;
    AgentInfo_Timer.Elapsed += LoadAgentInfo;
    AgentInfo_Timer.Enabled = true;
}

public void LoadAgentInfo(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    TextView TextView1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtPortfolioValue);      
    TextView1.Text = "This is TextView 1";
}
```

The TextView is inside the `Resource.Layout.AgentSummary`.
The timer runs fine every second!

But when I call the `LoadAgentInfo(null, null);` it says that the TextView inside that function is a null reference. The reason for that is that I use 2 layouts in one page using a ViewPager.

I already tried to inflate the layout from where the id's came from like this:

```
var InflatedAgentSummary = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AgentSummary, null);
TextView TextView1 = 
     InflatedAgentSummary.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtPortfolioValue);
```

But then the TextView never changes!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that the textview with Id `txtPortfolioValue` is part of the layout set for that activity. How does the code for that activity looks on the `OnCreate` method?

Comment: Well, the layout where the TextView is from, is inside a Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager

Comment: I will edit the code to the more similar version I have

Comment: I have edited the question and code

Comment: if the TextView is in another view, in this case the `ViewPager`, then you won't be able to find it from the activity. This is the reason you are having a null reference. `FindViewById` only finds Ids of views in the Layout file you set with the `SetContentLayout` method. Here you might need to find a way of exposing a method from that view.

Comment: Can someone provide me with an example

Comment: I still need some help, because inflating a layout doesn't work, so what am I supposed to do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must cache the reference to the inflated `AgentSummary` view and use it to get access to your `TextView`:

```
private View _agentSummary;

public void LoadOrderPage()
{
    Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager SummaryWalletSwitcher = FindViewById<Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager>(Resource.Id.SummaryWalletSwitcher);

    List<View> viewlist = new List<View>();
    _agentSummary = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AgentSummary, null, false);
    viewlist.Add(_agentSummary);
    viewlist.Add(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AgentWallet, null, false));
    SummaryWalletAdapter ViewSwitchAdapter = new SummaryWalletAdapter(viewlist);
    SummaryWalletSwitcher.Adapter = ViewSwitchAdapter;

    LoadAgentInfo(null, null);

    Timer AgentInfo_Timer = new Timer();
    AgentInfo_Timer.Interval = 1000;
    AgentInfo_Timer.Elapsed += LoadAgentInfo;
    AgentInfo_Timer.Enabled = true;
}

public void LoadAgentInfo(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    TextView TextView1 = _agentSummary.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtPortfolioValue);      
    TextView1.Text = "This is TextView 1";
}
```

The reason why the text didn't change in your attempt at this is you inflated a new instance of `AgentSummary`, so you actually changed the text on this new `InflatedAgentSummary` instance, which was immediately thrown away after `LoadAgentInfo` ended.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed my problem.